# Create multiple empty directories in Amazon S3 using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to S3 and I am trying to create multiple directories in Amazon S3 using java by only making one call to S3.
I could only come up with this :-

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentLength(0);

InputStream emptyContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);

PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucket,
      "test/tryAgain/", emptyContent, metadata);

s3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

But the problem with this while uploading 10 folders (`when the key ends with "/" in the console we can see the object as a folder` ) is that I have to make 10 calls to S3.

But I want to do a create all the folders at once like we do a batch delete using `DeleteObjectsRequest`.
Can anyone please suggest me or help me how to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more specific as to what you're trying to do (or avoid doing)?

If you're primarily concerned with the cost per PUT, I don't think there is a way to batch 'upload' a directory with each file being a separate key and avoid that cost.  Each PUT (even in a batch process) will cost you the price per PUT.

If you're simply trying to find a way to efficiently and recursively upload a folder, check out the uploadDirectory() method of TransferManager.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#uploadDirectory-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-boolean-

```
public MultipleFileUpload uploadDirectory(String bucketName,
                                      String virtualDirectoryKeyPrefix,
                                      File directory,
                                      boolean includeSubdirectories)
```

Comment: I have ten empty directories. I just want to upload them at once to S3

Comment: The MultipleFileUpload method should work, though I have never used it.  Use true for the includeSubdirectories parameter.

Comment: I actually want to create multiple empty directories in S3 . I dont want to upload them from local storage

Comment: Your original question stated "But I want to do a batch upload of all the folders at once".  You don't want to create the folders and upload the contents of the folders, you just want to create the folders?  You should amend your question accordingly, though I don't have an answer off hand.